# remote access is not supported for transaction isolation level snapshot - is this conditional?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, transactions, isolation-level

Folks - apologies for rehashing this topic as I see even here on Stack, there are so many questions on the topic already.

But I find myself in an interesting place and I'm hoping you can help.

High level Question: can SQL SERVER have the leeway to decide that a view should be wrapped in a ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT?

I know that sounds like a crazy question but I'm trying to exhaust all avenues per an issue I'm encountering.

I'm working with an application that runs 35 queries to retrieve data from another database via **Link Server**. The queries are simple selects against one table respectively. All DB operations are carried out against SQL SERVER, and retrieval code is ADO.NET/c#, etc.

34 of the queries work flawlessly - but there's this one bad apple, and for it, I get the **transaction isolation level snapshot** issue.

I've also tested data retrieval outside of the application and when I implement the below snippet on the "problem" query, I also get the issue:

```
using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
```

However, when I do **NOT** implement it on said query, all is well.
I've also tested this against the other queries - with and without "Shapshot" - and my results are predictable... With "Shapshot" in place, no queries process... When not implemented, all queries process...

My results suggest that the application is responsible for changing up the data retrieval strategy.

Per their knowledge base, I found this: `Locking is handled by the database level (MS SQL Server/Oracle) and not by "us". Generally, locking is row level but the optimizer may choose something different`

Unfortunately I don't have native access to the boiler-plate application code responsible for data retrieval.  I suspect that this particular query/table has one or more key words - either in the column or query/table naming - that trigger the application to use an alternate retrieval strategy.  Per the developer forums, I've asked of this is the case and I'm awaiting a reply...

Anyway back to their mention of `the optimizer may choose something different`- their optimizer, or perhaps the database optimizer? Can SQL SERVER be set up to make a "judgement call" ? Is the statement unclear or do I just not enough of SQL SERVER and its capabilities?

I know it seems like a crazy question but I really want to knock out all possible avenues here.
Thank you kindly for suspending your disbelieve and humoring that crazy post :)

Comment: The quote you found in the knowledge base concerns locking techniques (row-level vs. table-level) and not isolation levels (serializable, snapshot, etc.).  The application must be specifying the snapshot isolation level for the single problem query.  Without a code change, I don't believe you can fix this.

Comment: Agreed - Apparently objects with the word "valuation" (perhaps because of the sensitive nature implied) cause the application to build the transaction.  Once I changed the view name, the data returned to the client successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently objects with the word "valuation" (perhaps because of the sensitive nature implied) cause the application to build the transaction. Once I changed the view name, the data returned to the client successfully.

So yes the application was/is the issue.